# removing downloaded images when RestKit delete Objects

Tags: restkit-0.20

I want RestKit to automatically download object's image property (i.e my site.com/images/photo01.jpg) and when removing that object after syncing with server delete its downloaded images.

an example:

```
product 
{
  name:product1,
  image:www.mysite.com/images/photo01.jpg
}
```

after syncing with core data

```
product
{
  name:product1,
  image: /documents/photo01.jpg
}
```

here I want RestKit automatically download the image and assign local path as product image property.

and after syncing with server if I have deleted that object on the server, RestKit delete that image file in the local store too.

is that possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe RestKit will manage images for you? Have you researched or considered any other options?

Comment: I know RestKit is an Object Mapper. I think this idea will be a useful extension for RestKit. supposed I should write it manually to do this! I will Post my solution here